# When to use an adverb/adjective

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

Sometimes I get confused on when I should be using an adverb or an adjective. What's a good rule set?

For example, one can respond to a question with "bona" or "bone" - but when do I use which?

Comment: Any examples?...

Comment: @michau Well I'm looking for a rule set that can work in all scenarios.

Comment: You said you sometimes got confused. Can you give some examples of cases when you get confused?

Comment: @michau Such as when the word is on its own.

Comment: The general rule is that when you want to modify the meaning of a noun, you use an adjective, and when you want to modify the meaning of something else, you use an adverb. If you want a more precise answer, you need to give examples of specific sentences that make you confused whether an adverb or an adjective should be used.

Answer (score 6):

Adjectives describe nouns; that's basically all they do. So if there isn't a noun or pronoun to modify, you use the adverb form.

- *Mi estas freneza*; *freneza* describes *mi*
- *Kia freneza virino mi estas!*; *freneza* describes *virino*
- *Mi parolas freneze*; *freneze* describes the verb *parolas*, not a noun or pronoun
- *Estas freneze, ke mi parolis tiel al li*; *freneze* describes the *ke* phrase, not a noun or pronoun
- *Kiel freneze!*; *freneze* describes an unspecified situation, again, no noun or pronoun.

Note that adjectives can describe nouns through linking verbs:

- *Mi batis lin senkonscia* (*mi batis lin tiel, ke li estis senkonscia*)
- *Mi batis lin senkonscie* (*senkonscie, mi batis lin*)

Note the two different meanings!

Answer (score 1):

- Bona = a certain thing is good.
- Bone = a situation is good.

It is more common to use **Bone** by default. You can say **Bona** if you are referring to a noun. Example, your friend bought a new videogame and you say **Bona** because you like the game. However, **Bone** would work in that situation as well.